# PDO code and PHP undefined error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code to connect to database

```
class dbConn{
public $dbname='database';
private $dbhost='localhost';
private $dbusername='username';
private $dbpassword='password';


protected static $db;
private function __construct() {

try {

self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbusername, $dbpassword );
self::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {

echo "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

}


public static function getConnection() {


if (!self::$db) {

new dbConn();
}


return self::$db;
}

}




class Mysql{

    function showTables(){
                $db = dbConn::getConnection();

                $query=$db->query("show tables");

                $fetchArray = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach($fetchArray as $index=>$val) {
                            echo $val;
                          }
    }
}

$obj=new Mysql;
$obj->showTables();
```

Problem i am facing is if i directly use the database login details into pdo statement like this :

```
self::$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'root', 'pass');
```

I don't have any issue.But if i use like i stated above taking variables and storing values in to them.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbhost 

Notice: Undefined variable: dbname 

Notice: Undefined variable: dbusername 

Notice: Undefined variable: dbpassword
```

Following Error comes ,Also In other class it fails to connect to database too.

Can anyone tell me whats the problem in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$this` when accessing class properties - `$this` is the current object.

Example:

```
try {
  self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->dbhost.';dbname='.$this->dbname, $this->dbusername, $this->dbpassword );
  self::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When you call `$dbhost` you're looking for a variable within the current scope, in this instance the constructor. `$dbhost` and `$this->dbhost` are two different things in this case.

Comment: Thanks for explaining so simply. I got your point. Can you tell me is this thing with constructor only. Or Can't we use global variable then.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the constructor, it's just the scope of variables. Take a read of this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - it will explains all of this.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to

```
self::$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->dbhost.';dbname='.$this->dbname, $dbusername, $this->dbpassword );
```